# Way to run SQLCMD without storing password in text format

Tags: sql-server, database-recommendation

Is there a way to run sqlcmd from a batch file where I don't want to store the password in plain text format. I have done some research and found the system variables method(store password in system variables) but the requirement is not to store a password in text format anywhere in the system.

The user that is logging into the system should not be able to see the password for sql server and still run the batch file containing sqlcmd and restore command

Any help, pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You can use PowerShell to store the credentials in an encoded object, and use that to interface with SQL Server. Do you NEED to use SQLCMD, or do you think you can utilize the interfaces provided via PowerShell? I've found that a few lines of PowerShell supersedes SQLCMD.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Please share the powershell lines that you found.

Comment: if you can use mrdenny's reply, that would be the best bet. But if you MUST use SQLCMD with a SQL Server authentication (and not Windows) I can dig up some code for you. Keep in mind, although the password is stored as a SecureString, it can be cracked fairly easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Logins, then basically, no.  You'll want to have sqlcmd use the person's domain login to connect to the SQL Instance (the -E parameter instead of -U and -P).  You can use a login trigger to ensure that they are only able to connect via sqlcmd if you want to prevent them from logging in via SQL Server management studio (it isn't a perfect fix, but it'll stop 99% of people).